# How to insert value in a nested mongodb document?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, mongodb

I have this document:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63cf19337c2df5fe442a2b69"
  },
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1674516787623"
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1675035206032"
    }
  },
  "clientIp": "89.132.225.21",
  "products": {
    "6cc5a480-91f0-4aa8-975c-013d6bd155a3": {
      "currency": "EUR",
      "title": "VVV",
      "price": "12",
      "barionId": "aa@aa.hu",
      "ratingTimeLength": 12
    }
  }
}
```

I would insert like this:

```js
const userId = req.query.userId
            const productId = req.query.productId
            const token = authorization.slice(7)
            const userJWT = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET) as JwtPayload
            const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId
            const id = new ObjectId().toHexString()
            await collection.updateOne(
                { _id: ObjectId(userId), [`products.${productId}`]: { $exists: true } },
                {
                    $set: {
                        [`products.$.payments.${id}`]: {
                            createdAt: new Date(),
                            createdBy: userJWT.userId,
                        },
                    },
                },
                { upsert: true }
            )
```

But it raise:

> 2023-01-29T23:43:33.653Z  1a42849c-d5aa-4127-8fdc-9169c1c6c405    ERROR   MongoServerError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.

When I query record in Compass, it returns the document:

```json
{
"_id": ObjectId("63cf19337c2df5fe442a2b69"),
"products.6cc5a480-91f0-4aa8-975c-013d6bd155a3": {
"$exists": true
}
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: The `products` field is an object instead of an array. On the other hand, it is suggested not to use dynamic values like `6cc5a480-91f0-4aa8-975c-013d6bd155a3` as field names as it is considered anti-pattern and introduce extra complexity to queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access the `products` property directly with:

```
await collection.updateOne(
  { _id: ObjectId(userId), [`products.${productId}`]: { $exists: true } },
  {
    $set: {
      [`products.payments.${id}`]: {
        createdAt: new Date(),
        createdBy: userJWT.userId,
      },
    },
  },
  { upsert: true }
);
```